# Extend component with Input/Output

Tags: angular

Is it possible to extend a component in Angular 2 and still use the inputs and outputs in the parent?

```
export class Book {
  @Input() name;
}

export class EBook extends Book {
  @Input() downloadUrl;
  @Input() size;
}
```

When I try to extend a component everything inside the class works except the code that need attributes/decorators, like inputs and outputs. 
I made a plunker that illustrates the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/cfTKgScbaXMmEMoGY0zr

Book is a base component with one input/output Name.

EBook inherits from Book and adds input/output DownloadUrl, Size.

As you can see in the plunker, EBook doesn't get a name since the input is defined in Book and not in EBook

Answer (score 7):

As for the current version of Angular (7.0.1 while writing this), your use case is perfectly supported. And the [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5415) linked by Oliver has been closed.

Created an example Stackblitz (only highlighting input decorators):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fepmtp

Answer (score 5):

as for rc4, input decorators are only inherited if the sub-class has no input decorators itself.
otherwise you have to copy all the declarations.

its a known issue, you can follow up here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5415